# Efficient parsing of json metric data from REST API

Tags: javascript, json

What is the standard way of efficently parsing metric data encoded in JSON? Currently the way I know is that the entire JSON is parsed and then values can be examined. But this means taking memory and time all along making the user wait. If instead the data can be parsed value by value, then visualization can kick in (e.g. start drawing points on a graph) and also some of the parsing may be avoided (e.g. if returning data for one time range, while displaying a shorter one, allowing to expand the range without an additional query).

Is using jsonp recommended (where each data element or block of elements is returned wrapped in parse() method call)? Any other thechniques?

Note that I don't want to work with websockets or other event mechanisms. In my case the server has all the data ready and I just want to improve the client side parsing & display.